# Eager asker on a specific tag

Tags: discussion

[three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/three.js) suffers from horrible question quality, and bad etiquette (mostly as unaccepted answers).

However I'm seeing a different pattern as of recent. One poster is asking good questions (at least title wise), accepting answers and such, but the QA turns into a conversation that spills into the comments.

It's also obvious that the person is working on a specific project and that these questions are tied together.

[Three.js: Passing array of textures to shaderMaterial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50011542/three-js-passing-array-of-textures-to-shadermaterial)
[GLSL: Sending variable number of textures to sampler2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50067030/glsl-sending-variable-number-of-textures-to-sampler2d)
[WebGL: Count the number of rendered vertices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086576/webgl-count-the-number-of-rendered-vertices)
[Three.js: Interpreting renderer.info.render output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50069146/three-js-interpreting-renderer-info-render-output)

Not the best question, but yielded a really good answer:
[Three.js indexed BufferGeometry vs. InstancedBufferGeometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50077508/three-js-indexed-buffergeometry-vs-instancedbuffergeometry)

Which unfortunately the OP didn't understand. It was interpreted as "people going crazy":
[Three.js: When and how often are attributes passed to GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50107397/three-js-when-and-how-often-are-attributes-passed-to-gpu)

And finally, i think that this would be a great question, if the example provided was meaningful.
[GLSL: When does the fragment shader exit / return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50108853/glsl-when-does-the-fragment-shader-exit-return)

So this final example is the one that prompted me to post this. Because it's obviously a continuation of these previous questions / a specific project, the code ended up being more or less meaningless. A different example though feels like could provide a much more valuable answer. When i attempted to write an answer "disguised as a question", the goal was to help improve the question and maybe get a better answer. It failed.

Looking for glsl branching though, it seems like it has been asked:
[How to force GLSL branching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444701/how-to-force-glsl-branching)

And more specifically may be a duplicate of:
[GLSL branching behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299506/glsl-branching-behaviour))

Is there anything wrong here? A lot of the three.js/webgl/glsl stuff is documented and I have a feeling that there can be a lot more of these questions coming in, which may not be the worst thing, but it does feel that the quality could improve.

Comment: It's familiar behaviour. I've seen strings of questions starting with "How do I start", and then one function at a time getting added – copied straight from the *previous* question. Lots of questions, lots of answers, and a very happy customer. All Is Well™

Comment: "People going crazy" describing the previous response or the three.js community doesn't sound like a happy customer :) But that's beside the point, i think it gradually may reduce the quality of questions (starting with one thats good, but tapering off)

Comment: I don't see anything particularly wrong. Stack Overflow has built in limits, its not like this person can spam a hundred questions in a single day so what they're doing is within the accepted limits of the site. Just vote honestly on the questions, being careful not to focus on this one person too much as that is considered targeted voting.